# Solaris 10 kernel source

Tags: open-source, kernel, solaris, solaris-10, opensolaris

I am trying to locate the source code of either Solaris 10 or its kernel, as it used to be part of the OpenSolaris project. Do you have any ideas?

I was able to find the OpenSolaris source as there are forks (e.g Schillix,open Indiana).
Are there any Solaris 10 - based ?

I basically want to modify the kernel.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solaris 10 kernel source was never released as open source.   OpenSolaris started after the Solaris 10 release, using the source from the development branch which became Solaris 11.  The work to separate the parts of Solaris that could be open sourced or had to be kept closed (due to third party rights) was never done for Solaris 10.

Solaris 10 kernel source was available for purchase from Sun under proprietary license terms, but I believe Oracle is no longer selling that either.

Answer (score 0):

Source Code for Open Source Software Components of Oracle Solaris can be found below:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/opensource/systems-solaris-1562786.html

However, I haven't checked yet if it contains kernel source code.

Comment: Those releases contain the source code for software written outside Oracle, which Oracle is required to publish under the terms of licenses like GPL or MPL.   It does not contain the sources Sun/Oracle wrote on their own and are not required to release, like most of the kernel.